# ¿Cómo podría usar un archivo iCal para eliminar un evento ya creado?

Tags: java, icalendar

Tengo un código en Java el cuál se encarga de generar un archivo iCal, el cual se importa en un calendario de Outlook y crea un evento, mi duda está en que sí hay forma de crear un archivo de ese tipo el cual a la hora de importarlo pueda eliminar un evento que ya esté creado, no sé si sea posible y si lo es agradecería que me pudieran regalar una fuente para poder implementarlo.

Según lo que encontré se colocan las propiedades de `STATUS:CANCELLED` y `METHOD:CANCEL` y pues utilicé el siguiente código para intentar hacer esto:

```
private static net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar createCalendar(VEvent event) {
        net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar cal = new net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar();
        cal.getComponents().add(event);
        cal.getProperties().add(new ProdId("-//Events Calendar//iCal4j 1.0//EN"));
        cal.getProperties().add(Method.CANCEL);
        cal.getProperties().add(Status.VEVENT_CANCELLED);
        cal.getProperties().add(Version.VERSION_2_0);
        cal.getProperties().add(CalScale.GREGORIAN);

        //Agregamos el evento
        cal.getComponents().add(event);
        return cal;
    }
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

> INFORMACIÓN: ical4j.properties not found.
>   net.fortuna.ical4j.model.ValidationException: Invalid property: STATUS
>       at net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar.validate(Calendar.java:297)
>       at net.fortuna.ical4j.model.Calendar.validate(Calendar.java:257)
>       at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarOutputter.output(CalendarOutputter.java:96)
>       at net.fortuna.ical4j.data.CalendarOutputter.output(CalendarOutputter.java:83)
>       at com.bmsoftware.ical.Generador.exportFile(Generador.java:142)
>       at com.bmsoftware.ical.Main.main(Main.java:25)

E Intenté ponerlo directamente en el documento, pero no funcionó la importación, así qué, estoy en las mismas, si alguien puede ayudarme, se lo agradezco.

Comment: Bienvenidx a Stack Overflow en español. 
Las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: Has intentado algo?